Gnuplot, use time related X-axis variable and show day label (when it changes ideally)
I have cvs data out from sqlite3, a small edited sample:



conTime
dayXS_date
Ref-AHx
Ref-Cx10
Bed1-AH
Bed2-AH
Bed1-Cx10
Bed2-Cx10




6466
2024/05/14
510
149
583
604
210
222


6467
2024/05/14
510
147
587
601
210
221


6468
2024/05/14
515
143
590
599
210
220


6469
2024/05/14
515
144
582
597
209
220


6470
2024/05/14
517
144
589
596
209
219


6471
2024/05/14
526
144
586
594
208
219


6472
2024/05/14
538
139
583
590
207
218


6473
2024/05/14
542
135
581
587
206
217


6474
2024/05/14
542
134
597
584
205
216


6475
2024/05/14
538
133
597
580
205
215


.........









6690
2024/05/20
466
206
638
602
232
235


6691
2024/05/20
486
197
651
600
236
240


6692
2024/05/20
510
189
646
640
236
241


6693
2024/05/20
506
181
638
657
235
241


6694
2024/05/20
527
171
613
630
234
238


6695
2024/05/20
528
159
605
662
232
238


6696
2024/05/20
507
145
593
658
230
235


6697
2024/05/20
493
136
587
647
228
232


6698
2024/05/20
485
131
585
587
227
227


6699
2024/05/20
500
133
585
628
226
229



If I plot columns 3+ against 1 all is well.
I just would like to get where the days are (ideally each day start) along the x-axis but I do not want every datapoint with the same date label.
conTime is adjusted in sql to give me a smoothly increasing number at appropriate granularity for my needs, so I really need that to be the x-axis basis.
In pseudo code I would like to
(plot) label column_text(2) datapoints 20;
or
(plot) label column_text(2) at col(1),-15 'when it changes';
I have spent many hours playing with ideas from www. Current remnants of them are in below, I mostly cut and paste bits interactively into Gnuplot sessions...
If I got xticlabels or similar working there would be too many. Generating in sql null or changed date might work but that also is learning to do and a side path  from what I need to achieve...
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d"
set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0,-4 

#plot first line heavier weight as clearer ref etc.
#plot  "sqlout.csv" using 1:2 with text dp 10, \
plot "sqlout.csv" using 1:3 with lp lt 1 lw 3 title columnhead(3), \
 "sqlout.csv" using 1:4 with lp lt 2 lw 3 title columnhead(4), \
for [col=5:*] "sqlout.csv" using 1:col with lp ls col title columnhead(col)
#pause -1 "Return to end..."

#pause 2
plot "sqlout.csv" using 2:3 with lp lt 1 lw 3 title columnhead(3), \
 "sqlout.csv" using 2:4 with lp lt 2 lw 3 title columnhead(4), \
for [col=5:*] "sqlout.csv" using 2:col with lp ls col title columnhead(col)

By the way getting a table to work was PITA, adding | in SQL .
BIG CLUE: the  | ---| --- | cells seem essential???
I have, since posting, managed in sql to use LAG(dayXS_date) to only show where dates change and leave blank otherwise so plotting all near axis would now solve my problem, too. I don't know how to do that even!



conTime
dayXS_date
Ref-AHx
Ref-Cx10
Bed1-AH
Bed2-AH
Bed1-Cx10
Bed2-Cx10




6466
2024/05/14
510
149
583
604
210
222


6467
-,
510
147
587
601
210
221


6468
-,
515
143
590
599
210
220



Seems I can't make table here with blank cells! Previews Fine!

Why do you create a sophisticated table if your data is a simple text file, i.e. CSV? Just copy&paste your CSV file here on StackOverflow between a pair of triple backquotes. So, as I understand you want to plot daily data with a little time shift, correct? How many data point are typically within one day? Is this a fixed number or variable within a certain range?

That was what I tried first, but it seemed to run lines together no matter which block quote etc style I tried. maybe that is because it expects windows style line endings? I'm on MacOS, so *nix style by default. But thanks - that is what I thought was best to do...

If you look at my SQL below, I actually have to gather rows into columns. That is a time waster for me really especially when there are 10*2 categories!. Is there a way Gnuplot can handle reading the category from a locationID column and still produce the same output?? So my data lines would have columns:       .....     conTime, date, location, AH, Cx10

I don't know SQL, so I don't understand what you mean. If this is a new topic please ask a new question with a clear example of input data and detailed description of desired output graph (and ideally some gnuplot script attempt).

My current understanding of your question is the following: you have some time data, but the data has only a day-stamp (no time in hours/minutes). Since there are several datapoints from the same day, they would just plot at the same position on the time axis. Since you want to spread the data, you introduced a column conTime to distribute the data points a bit. Now, the question is how to spread the data over the day, correct?
Some comments:

using the smooth freq option, it is counted how many data point there are for each day. The datablock $Counts will contain the time (in seconds passed from Jan, 1st 1970) and the number of data points
getCounts() is a "look-up" function to return the data count depending on the day
the function spread(), initializes the counter c=0 and increases it by 1 every time the previous time t0 is identical to the current time t1. Every time there is a new day, the counter will be reset to c=0 and c0 gets the number of data point counts of that day. The function will actually return the fraction of 86400.*c/c0, i.e. the data is spread over the day (86400 seconds = 1 day).

Maybe, this can still be simplified.
Data: SO78513320.csv
Just for illustration, I introduced some extra data separated by commented lines for visibility.
conTime,dayXS_date,Ref-AHx,Ref-Cx10,Bed1-AH,Bed2-AH,Bed1-Cx10,Bed2-Cx10
6466,2024/05/14,510,149,583,604,210,222
6467,2024/05/14,510,147,587,601,210,221
6468,2024/05/14,515,143,590,599,210,220
6469,2024/05/14,515,144,582,597,209,220
6470,2024/05/14,517,144,589,596,209,219
6471,2024/05/14,526,144,586,594,208,219
6472,2024/05/14,538,139,583,590,207,218
6473,2024/05/14,542,135,581,587,206,217
6474,2024/05/14,542,134,597,584,205,216
6475,2024/05/14,538,133,597,580,205,215
#
6480,2024/05/17,538,133,597,580,205,215
6480,2024/05/17,528,143,587,570,215,225
6480,2024/05/17,518,153,577,560,225,235
6480,2024/05/17,538,133,597,580,205,215
#
6690,2024/05/20,466,206,638,602,232,235
6691,2024/05/20,486,197,651,600,236,240
6692,2024/05/20,510,189,646,640,236,241
6693,2024/05/20,506,181,638,657,235,241
6694,2024/05/20,527,171,613,630,234,238
6695,2024/05/20,528,159,605,662,232,238
6696,2024/05/20,507,145,593,658,230,235
6697,2024/05/20,493,136,587,647,228,232
6698,2024/05/20,485,131,585,587,227,227
6699,2024/05/20,500,133,585,628,226,229

Script:
### spread data of one day over 24 hours
reset session

FILE = "SO78513320.csv"

set datafile separator comma
myFmt = "%Y/%m/%d"

set table $Counts
    set format x "%.0f"
    plot FILE u (timecolumn(2,myFmt)):(1) smooth freq
unset table

getCounts(t) = sum [i=5:|$Counts|-2] ($Counts[i]==t ? int(word($Counts[i],2)) : 0)
spread(col)  = (t=timecolumn(col,myFmt), $0==0 ? (c=0, c0=getCounts(t),t1=t) : NaN, \
               t0=t1, t1=t, t0==t1 ? c=c+1 : (c=0, c0=getCounts(t)), t+86400.*c/c0)

set format x "%Y\n%m/%d" timedate
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05
set key out
set grid x,y

plot FILE u (spread(2)):3 w lp pt 7 lw 3 ti columnhead, \
       '' u (spread(2)):4 w lp pt 7 lw 3 ti columnhead, \
     for [i=5:*] '' u (spread(2)):i w lp pt 7 lw 1 ti columnhead
### end of script

Result:

Addition:
A slightly simpler script if you assume a fixed maximum number of datapoints per day (here: c0=20).
Script:
### spread data of one day over 24 hours
reset session

FILE = "SO78513320.csv"

set datafile separator comma
myFmt = "%Y/%m/%d"

set format x "%Y\n%m/%d" timedate
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05
set key out
set grid x,y

c0 = 20   # max. datapoints per day
spread(col) = (t=timecolumn(col,myFmt), $0==0 ? (c=0, t1=t) : NaN, \
               t0=t1, t1=t, t0==t1 ? c=c+1 : c=0, t+86400.*c/c0)

plot FILE u (spread(2)):3 w lp pt 7 lw 3 ti columnhead, \
       '' u (spread(2)):4 w lp pt 7 lw 3 ti columnhead, \
     for [i=5:*] '' u (spread(2)):i w lp pt 7 lw 1 ti columnhead
### end of script

Result:


That is all excellent and useful examples of features I did not know existed. I will post what I did myself in the interval to get closer to a solution as that may also be useful to an audience... It may take me a while to ingest everything and work out which the best way to proceed with this sort of work.... There are many other features you used I like, such as the grid

Re the time data: effectively I have a slot number 0-143 for 10 minute buckets across the day. That is added to 1000 x integer day since I started to record data so I have timeID, an integer for compactness but can link to a table of day info with the date text and a few other relevant facts about the day (eg output of PVpanels, rainfall, notes)

Still lots to learn and ingest in what you gave! The reset session, tables, why $ in $Counts I have to checkout etc etc. So many thanks... The spread method would slightly mis-draw when data points are not collected due to internet/ISPserver failures - there have been a few data outages.... Data using slot number would be in the correct place. I can certainly set c0 to 143!

I'm not sure how the simpler code would work where I average down slots to get fewer data points per day when plotting longer periods? [But that may be my current ignorance!] ie if I save generic Gnuplot script code to use for a variety of sql outputs then data points per day will vary but never exceed 144 (0 to 143).

I actually have many more data series to plot, about 20 and for a large variety of SQL queries. Is the spread(2) function called and run every time, if so, could this be avoided by storage in a table just once? I know that all series should have the same number of readings (unless there is physical damage) even if, ideally, the Gnuplot code will not be told by my edit before the run what that number is.

With a bit more pondering it is obvious the simpler code will compress a smaller number of points into the first fraction of a day... The set table documentation is interesting, so we output to a table (in memory I assume) and then read that back in later.

@Cwinte in order to check what might go wrong, please show a data example for which the script "slightly mis-draws" the data. The spread() function in the first example is exactly made for the case if there are a variable type of datapoints per day. These numbers are stored in the datablock $Counts. In gnuplot console after having run the script, type print $Counts to see.

While I was waiting to see responses I tried to do more in SQL. I did manage to get changes of day only in a column... but it made problems in that the blanks were ignored and Gnuplot took data from the next column to the right, which confused me for a while. In the end I got SQL to give a . when the date was the same and it plotted not too bad.
   # time based data, date text in column 2 while 1 is numeric of some kind (sorted but not user friendly)
    set term pdfcairo size 17in, 12in
    fdate=system("date +%F,%H.%M")
    set output sprintf('./sql2dyQRY%s.pdf', fdate)
    set key outside
    set size 0.98, 0.98
    set title "col2day SQLqry ".fdate font ",25";
    
    #plot first line heavier weight as clearer ref etc. Set y= (300) to position between my data areas
    plot  "sqlout.csv" using 1:(300):2 with labels rotate notitle, \
     "sqlout.csv" using 1:3 with lp lt 1 lw 3 title columnhead(3), \
     "sqlout.csv" using 1:4 with lp lt 2 lw 3 title columnhead(4), \
    for [col=5:*] "sqlout.csv" using 1:col with lp ls col title columnhead(col);
    unset output

select cast((timeID+(timeID%1000)*5.94)/30 as int) as "conTime", IIF(dayXS_date=LAG(dayXS_date)over(order by dayID) ,'.', dayXS_date) as dateLbl, cast(avg(IIF(locationID=1,AHx100/2,NULL)) as int) as "Ref-AHx", cast(avg(IIF(locationID=1,Cx10,NULL)) as int) as "Ref-Cx10",  cast(avg(IIF(locationID=3,AHx100/2,NULL)) as int) as "Bed1-AH",  cast(avg(IIF(locationID=7,AHx100/2,NULL)) as int) as "Bed2-AH",  cast(avg(IIF(locationID=3,Cx10,NULL)) as int) as "Bed1-Cx10", cast(avg(IIF(locationID=7,Cx10,NULL)) as int) as "Bed2-Cx10" from history, DayInfo where timeID>193999 and dayID=cast(timeID/1000 as int) group by "conTime";
conTime  dateLbl     Ref-AHx  Ref-Cx10  Bed1-AH  Bed2-AH  Bed1-Cx10  Bed2-Cx10
-------  ----------  -------  --------  -------  -------  ---------  ---------
6466     2024/05/14  510      149       583      604      210        222
6467         .       510      147       587      601      210        221
6468         .       515      143       590      599      210        220
6469         .       515      144       582      597      209        220
6470         .       517      144       589      596      209        219

Not sure I am allowed to post an image, I have all the data points and the dates rotated mark off the days while a row of dots match each data point. I would not be able to add a meaningful grid I suspect...
